# Compare a edittext with a listview in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, compare

I can't compare a `listview` with a `edittext`. I want to make compare, if
`tampil` equal `list1`, "data tersedia" will appear, if not equal, "data tidak tersedia" will appear.

Any solution?

I have tried changing tampil toString(), changing comparison equals with
operator "==", but it doesn't work.

---MainActivity.kt---

```
package com.indraalfendipurba.sortir1
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var input: EditText
    lateinit var button: Button
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            input = findViewById(R.id.input)
            button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        val list = mutableListOf<String>("satu", "dua")
        val data = ArrayAdapter(applicationContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list)
            lv.adapter = data
        val list1 = list.iterator()//untuk mengecek kondisi nilai atw element pada list
        val tampil = input.text
        var found = false
            button.setOnClickListener {
        for (n in list1) {
           if (n.equals(tampil)) {
                found = true
                break
                }
        }
           if (found) {
               Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "data tersedia", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "data tidak tersedia ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
           }
       }
    }
}
```

-----activity_main.xml-----

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"[enter image description here][1]
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
            android:layout_width="352dp"
            android:layout_height="215dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" android:id="@+id/lv"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/input"/>
    <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:layout_marginStart="16dp" android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="84dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:ems="10"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:id="@+id/input" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lv"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button" android:hint="masukan data"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add:

```
found = false
```

at the beginning of the button's listener.  
Also why do you iterate through `list1` which is an iterator object (why do you need it)? 
 Iterate through `list`:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    found = false
    for (n in list) {
        if (n.equals(tampil)) {
            found = true
            break
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "data tersedia", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "data tidak tersedia ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your correct, I missed about it(list1 and list). actually I have problem in my real code, so I created code example about my problem to resolve it easier. The problem is, I want to get data from listview(data from firebase) that has appeared, and compare it with edittext. If the data is the same, there is action will be execute and vice versa. The listview id is "lv", and the edittext id is "input". Can you give solution from this case? please

Comment: You must post a question with all the relevant code, where you explain in details and not in general what you do and what you expect.